# turn urls into links but not break images src or Flash embeds in php

Tags: php, regex

I had a code that turned `http://` in to `<a` links. the issue with it was that it would break images and flash players. It was using Regex. Does anyone know of a Regex code that would do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you describe it obviously, especially its relation with flash players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That regex will work fine, but just include more measures to make sure that a leading src are excluded.  I assume it breaks by src="http://myimage" becoming src="